# VS Code Azure functions deployment failing with Python Version 3.9

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a function app (python) in the azure portal which is in python version 3.7.
The FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION of the function app is ~3.
When I deploy the function python) from VS code to update the function in the portal, I'm able to deploy and the update is reflected in the azure portal.

But when I change the python version to 3.9 and update FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to ~4 in the Azure portal and try to deploy the function(python) from VS code to update the function in the portal, deployment failed with error **"deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build."**

The deployment is failing only after upgrading to version 3.9.

Could anyone please help me to understand why am I getting this error and how can we fix this?

Comment: have you tried with py3.8?

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade the Python Version 3.7 to 3.9

**Step 1**: Update `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `4` and Python version of Azure Function App in the Portal using the cmdlet:

```
az functionapp config set --name krishpyfunapp37to39 --resource-group HariTestRG --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.9"
```

[image]
[image]

Make Sure Runtime Version is 4 in the General Settings of the Azure Function App Configuration Menu.

**Step 2**:

Select the Python Interpreter as 3.9.x version in your Azure Functions Project using the VS Code IDE:
(**`Ctrl + Shift + P`** and Type as "**`Python Interpreter`**")

[image]

If the Virtual Environment is activated in the project, make sure you update the home path and version number in virtual environment folder of the project:

```
home = C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.9.13
```

[image]

**Note**: Update the code and packages that matches the Python version 3.9.x when upgrading/downgrading > Test and then deploy. So that, it will not break the code due to changes.

[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-python) for steps on migrating the Azure Functions versions 3.x to 4.x and Python Versions.